# Implement slow sorting algorithm

Tags: popularity-contest, sorting

All good coders know some good sorting algorithms like quicksort or merge sort. There is also slow sorting algorithms, e.g. bubble sort and insertion sort.

But those are such easy to implement and so, so efficient. Too efficient. Your task  is to create very slow sorting algorithm.

Please attach the [Big O notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) of your algorithm to your post to help us rate them. Also, please describe how your sorting algorithm works.

Input given trough STDIN. The first line contains number of arguments, and arguments are given after that. The arguments are integers in range from 0 to 10<sup>5</sup> and there are maximum 10<sup>3</sup> of them.

Output is list sorted and printed line by line into STDOUT sorted beginning from decending order.

You may not use any random numbers or any other random sources.

This is [popularity-contest](/questions/tagged/popularity-contest).

Comment: What stops me from sorting the array again and again , say, n^n times to increase the Big O ?

Comment: That depends... bogosort has a good best case.
How exactly will this be counted?

Comment: @MartinBüttner Bogobogosort

Comment: I just now saw that you could not use any random numbers or sources so I quess we can't shuffle either

Comment: You want to sort integers slowly? Why not use [sleep sort](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithms/Sleep_sort)? If that's still too fast for you then you make the sleep unit years! Or centuries!

Comment: Since the range of values is limited to 10^5, sleep sort actually has O(1) performance, regardless of how long the (fixed) sleep unit is.

Comment: That question was closed for not having clear winning criteria. I'm fairly certain we had a horrible sorting challenge before, but I can't seem to find one that doesn't at least have different rules and winning criteria.

Comment: @Tally, the solution to a question being closed isn't to post a duplicate which fixes (one of) its problems but to edit the original question and then request reopening.

Comment: I didn't realise, but on that note, what would then be the best course of action with the answer I made for the question?

Answer (score 6):

## Mathematica, Time complexity O(n * n!), Space complexity O(n!)

```
list = RandomInteger[10, 7]
(*{5, 5, 4, 10, 5, 10, 5}*)
permutations = Permutations@list;
Cases[permutations, l_ /; And @@ Thread[Most[RotateLeft@l - l] >= 0]][[1]]
(*{4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 10, 10}*)
```

This generates all permutations, discards all that aren't sorted, and then picks the first one.

Therefore, it will use O(n!) memory and O(n!) time to generate all the permutations. Then it will use O(n!) time again, to iterate through the permutations, while needing O(n) for *each* of them to check that they are sorted.

Note that this is both the worst case *and* best case complexity.

Answer (score 0):

## CJam, Time complexity O(n<sup>(2n+1)</sup>*log(n)), Space complexity O(n)

```
q~:Q,_#2#{Q$;}*Q$p
```

This sorts the array **n<sup>2n</sup> + 1** times using Merge Sort which has time complexity of **n log(n)**

But really, this can be extended to any time complexity with a final output in range of Big Integer.

(Don't) [try it online here](http://cjam.aditsu.net/)

Input is like:

```
[1 4 2 3 1 5 6 1 2344 343 1 2 3 23 1 2 32 1 2 3 4]
```

and output is the sorted array

A [graph comparing](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20x%20*%20%28%28x%20%5E%20x%29%20%5E%202%29%20*%20log%20%28x%29%20vs%20x%20*%20x!) **n * n!** with **n<sup>2n + 1</sup> * log(n)**